# Combining multiple sql statements into columns

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by, sum

I'm pretty new to SQL and I'm running something like this to pull out some data. But Currently I am running them one statement at a time and copying them to excel. Is there a way to run all these together? Level would be the same for each statement, but count(ID) will be different. There might also be some days where a level does not have any data.

```
select 
    count(ID), level 
from table1 
where createat >= "2013-11-22 00:00:00" and createat <= "2013-11-22 23:59:59" 
group by level;

select 
    count(ID), level 
from table1 
where createat >="2013-11-23 00:00:00" and createat <= "2013-11-23 23:59:59" 
group by level;

select 
    count(ID), level 
from table1 
where createat >= "2013-11-24 00:00:00" and createat <= "2013-11-24 23:59:59" 
group by level;
```

Thanks for the help! I'm hoping to learn more about how to write these.

Comment: 1) provide the type of database you use 2) use a date function to extract the day of the month from your date column, and use this to ease your query and group by day if this is what you want

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  level,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN createat>='2013-11-22' and createat<'2013-11-23' THEN id ELSE NULL END)   AS day_1_count,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN createat>='2013-11-23' and createat<'2013-11-24' THEN id ELSE NULL END)   AS day_2_count,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN createat>='2013-11-24' and createat<'2013-11-25' THEN id ELSE NULL END)   AS day_3_count
FROM
  table1
GROUP BY
  level
WHERE
  createat>='2013-11-22' and createat<'2013-11-25'
```

Although, it would probably make more sense to join on a table with the dates that you need, rather than hard code them.

Also, note that SQL works on a fixed number of columns, this does not work if you want one query for 3 days and then to reuse it for 5 days.  For that you need to keep it as one result per Row.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.level, SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(createat) = '2013-11-22' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(createat) = '2013-11-23' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(createat) = '2013-11-24' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day3
FROM table1 t
WHERE DATE(t.createat) >= "2013-11-22" AND DATE(t.createat) <= "2013-11-24" 
GROUP BY t.level;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT t.level, SUM(CASE WHEN t.createat >= "2013-11-22 00:00:00" AND t.createat <= "2013-11-22 23:59:59" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.createat >= "2013-11-23 00:00:00" AND t.createat <= "2013-11-23 23:59:59" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.createat >= "2013-11-24 00:00:00" AND t.createat <= "2013-11-24 23:59:59" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day3
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.createat >= "2013-11-22 00:00:00" AND t.createat <= "2013-11-24 23:59:59" 
GROUP BY t.level;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple edit to the query you posted is:

```
select count(ID), level 
from table1 
where createat >= "2013-11-22 00:00:00" and createat <= "2013-11-22 23:59:59" 
group by level
union
select count(ID), level 
from table1 
where createat >="2013-11-23 00:00:00" and createat <= "2013-11-23 23:59:59" 
group by level
union
select count(ID), level 
from table1 
where createat >= "2013-11-24 00:00:00" and createat <= "2013-11-24 23:59:59" 
group by level
```

However if you are trying to get the count, level value and date for each day then you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), level, CAST(createat AS DATE)
FROM table1
GROUP BY level, CAST(createat AS DATE)
```